# Pynput mouse listener freezing input

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pynput

I am making a program that toggles on and off by a holding a certain mouse button(using pynput). The problem is that after I start the code and hold the mouse button, while the class is being executed, there is lag in the movement of the cursor. How to fix the lag?

```
import time
import threading
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

delay = 0.01

button = Button.left
control = Controller()
running = False


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                control.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)



def process():
    click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
    click_thread.start()
    while running:
        click_thread.start_clicking()
    click_thread.stop_clicking()

    
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):  
    global running
    
    if button == mouse.Button.x2: 
        if pressed:
            if not running:  # to run only one `process`
                running = True
                threading.Thread(target=process).start()
        else:
            running = False



with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```